# Modifying existing classes and injecting new ones

Tags: java, jvm, agents

I'm working on a project that requires I use an agent to transform classes, I also need to add new classes. this all has to be done over the network, the end user downloads a jar that downloads classes to inject into the class loader and modify existing ones with a transformer. I have successfully done both of these things, but I was wondering if there is a better way, I did it using a class parser I wrote that transmitted the classes as JSON to the client where it used javasisst to rebuild them.

is there a better way to send new classes over the network and send modifications to be made to existing classes?

Comment: You question lacks the actual problem description. To “use an agent to transform classes” is not a problem but an attempted solution. We can’t  tell you whether there is a better way without knowing where the way leads to.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to incorporate the actual problem description. Don’t hesitate to be more detailed…